# Set a seasonal weekly event on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I set a seasonal weekly event  on Google Calendar? I want an event every Wednesday at 11 am but excluding the summer (excluding May to August). 
EDIT: I have many of these events.

Answer (score 1):

Set the first September's Wednesday as the start date and the next year last April's Wednesday as the end date. Repeat for the next cycle.

As end-users we could automatize the above procedure by using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start).

Another alternative is to create a "template" event, export it as CSV, then use an spreadsheet to create several events by "copy-pasting" or fillind down the columns that have the same data and manually editing the values that change for each event, then upload it to the calendar.

See [Export your Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?hl=en) to learn how to export a Google Calendar as CSV.

I suggest to this once a year or something similar (every two upto five years?) just in case that in the future changes should be made to the seasonal events like updating the event name among other event data.

Comment: Yes but every year I have to manually redo it, and I have tens of those events.

Comment: @Lupocci add those details to the question.

Comment: I added them. I now say I have many events.